# Bus Error when trying to write data into memory mapped file

Tags: c, linux, mmap

I'm seeing a bus error when I try to update the memory mapped region in a file. I Googled and come to know this happens when one attempts to perform read/write beyond mapped region. I already cross-checked and nothing seems to be wrong here. Here is a code:

```
typedef int fd_t;
#define free_pg_bitmap_size 1

typedef struct db_file_hdr_ {

    uint64_t allocated_pg_bitmap[free_pg_bitmap_size];

} db_file_hdr_t;


void *
disk_io_file_mmap (fd_t fd, uint64_t start_offset, uint64_t end_offset) {

    void *pptr = mmap (NULL, end_offset - start_offset, 
                                    PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, 
                                    fd, start_offset);

    assert (pptr);
    return pptr;
}

fd_t
db_file_open (const char* path) {
    FILE *file = fopen (path, "w+");
    if (!file) assert(0);
    fd_t fd = fileno (file);
    return fd;
}

static void 
db_file_init_hdr (fd_t fd) {
    int i;
    db_file_hdr_t *db_hdr = (db_file_hdr_t *)disk_io_file_mmap 
                          (fd, 0, sizeof (db_file_hdr_t));

    for (i = 0 ; i < free_pg_bitmap_size; i++) {
        db_hdr->allocated_pg_bitmap[i] = 0;         **<<<<< Bus Error here**
    }
    disk_file_unmap ( (void *)db_hdr, sizeof (db_file_hdr_t));
}


void
disk_io_create_disk_file (const char* path, fsize size) {

fd_t fd;

FILE *file = fopen (path, "w+");

if (!file) assert(0);

fd = fileno (file);

if (ftruncate(fd, size) == -1) {
    assert(0);
}

assert (fsync(fd) != -1);
fclose (file);
}

void
db_file_create_db_file (const char* path, uint64_t size) {

fd_t fd;

disk_io_create_disk_file (path, 
    sizeof (db_file_hdr_t) + 
    (DB_FILE_DEF_PAGE_CNT *  DB_PAGE_DEF_SIZE));

fd = db_file_open  (path);

/* initialize the Hdr of the DB file*/
db_file_init_hdr (fd);

close (fd);
}

int 
main (int argc, char **argv) {

/* Create a DB file on disk*/
db_file_create_db_file ("sample1.db", 0);
```

Comment: 1.  `assert()` is horrible for error checking. It will either kill your entire program, or it will reduce to a no-op depending on how your code is compiled.  2.  Your `db_file_open()` function leaks the `FILE *` pointer.  Just use [`open()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/open.html).  3.  Are you **sure** you're not trying to **extend** the file using `mmap()`?  That will not work - you'll get `SIGBUS` if you try...

Comment: The array has length `1` for some reason, so the loop should't index beyond bounds, but you have not checked the pointer returned by `disk_io_file_mmap()` which you dereference.

Comment: The pointer returned by `disk_io_file_mmap` was ok. No issues with that. @WeatherVane

Comment: Hm you've just changed one of the type definitions.

Comment: Well, this is broken: `assert (pptr);`  Check what `mmap()` returns on failure....

Comment: gns3@gns3vm:~/RDBMSImplementation$ ./exe
pptr = 0x7f973c25f000       <<< pptr returned by mmap
Bus error
@AndrewHenle

Comment: `#define int fd_t`?!?  Just what do you think **that** does???  Nowhere near what you think, I'd venture.  First, why would you even hide an `int` behind some other private type (which is **not** what that line does...).  Second, identifiers that end with `_t` are reserved on POSIX systems.

Comment: its a type error, it is actually 'typedef int fd_t;'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are checking for `mmap` failure incorrectly: `mmap` returns `MAP_FAILED`, which is not `NULL`. Also, as others have commented, using `assert()` to check for errors is *fundamentally* wrong.
2. You right-size the file with `ftruncate`, but then reopen it with `fopen (path, "w+");` in `db_file_open()`. From `man fopen`:

```
w+     Open for reading and writing.
       The file is created if it does not exist, otherwise it is truncated.
       The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file.
```

The *otherwise it is truncated* is the key part -- you negate the effect of the earlier `ftruncate` by performing `openat(AT_FDCWD, "sample1.db", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666)` (that's what `strace` shows on my system -- doubtless coming from the `fopen` implementation).

Since you've just emptied the file (truncated to `0` size), `SIGBUS` is *entirely expected*.

You can verify that this is in fact happening with `ls -l sample1.db` after the program crashes.